# BibLatex Chinese Characters in reference, XeLatex not an option

Tags: biblatex, cjk

I am need to cite chinese authors in my thesis. It works fine with Latex but not in BibLatex where I need to cite it within my refernces. Using Xelatex is not an option, as too many errors are showing when converting it. I tried several options before but none of them are working for Biblatex without Xelatex. Any new suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

I've been asked to post an example, an entry in my .bib file would look like this:

```
@misc{chin2012pat,
  author={彤陈},
  year={2012},
  title={Obtaining fatty acids from insect larvae},
  howpublished={Investigacion y Comercializacion
  Biotecnologica Omebit S.A, Santiago. US8895767 B2},
  note={Jun. 11, 2010},
}
```

As for what I've tried before: I tried to use a CJK block in biblatex, of course that didn't compile properly. I then tried to search stackexchange, unfortunately all solutions involve xelatex.

I don't have a lot of chinese references in my paper, so I was thinking there could be some way to "hardcode" it in, but I'm out of guesses.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Show an example how it works for you in latex. (But I would try to get rid of the xelatex errors, in the long run that's imho the better solution).

Comment: I use the CJKutf8 package and a \begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn} Block in the Text. I use a university issued template that's unfortunately incompatible with xelatex and would be quite a lot of work to fix.

Comment: A full MWE of what you have so far and what you tried with `biblatex` would greatly help us to make sure the solutions actually work for you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! As others have said, the terms of the question are rather generic and an example would be very useful.

Comment: If only for those of us who cannot write anything in Chinese to even test with. I suspect I'm not the only one who couldn't even create ***a*** minimal example matching the description in your question, vague though that description is.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I've updated the question with an example bibliography entry. As egreg noticed this is my first post on stackexchange, so thanks for your patience :)

Answer (score 4):

Calling `biblatex` with the option `bibencoding=utf8` ensures that unknown Unicode points will be saved as `\x{<code point>}` in the `.bbl` file. With the help of `\bibsetup` we can then change the meaning of `\x` to do what we prefer with its argument.

For instance, I defined `\x` to be `\chinesechar` (a macro name of my own invention), that loads a graphic file named `pia<code point>`, that I prepared with XeLaTeX; for example, this is `pia5f64.tex`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Songti SC}
\begin{document}
^^^^5f64
\end{document}
```

The other character is Unicode U+9648.

If you are able to coerce `CJKutf8` into producing a character from its Unicode, then this indirect method is not necessary. Unfortunately, the documentation seems to be only in Chinese.

I also added a `sortname` field to the bib entry, in order to get correct alphabetic sorting (I hope Google Translate guessed right).

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{chin2012pat,
  author={彤陈},
  sortname={{Chen Tong}},
  year={2012},
  title={Obtaining fatty acids from insect larvae},
  howpublished={Investigacion y Comercializacion
  Biotecnologica Omebit S.A, Santiago. US8895767 B2},
  note={Jun. 11, 2010},
}
@article{a,
  author={A. Uthor},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  year=2013,
}
@article{b,
  author={T. Best},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  year=2013,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\appto\bibsetup{\let\x\chinesechar}

\newcommand\chinesechar[1]{\includegraphics[height=\fontcharht\font`T]{pia#1}}

\begin{document}

\cite{chin2012pat}, \cite{a}, \cite{b}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Maybe better method

I did some blind experiment with `CJKutf8` and this seems to work.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{chin2012pat,
  author={{\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}彤陈\end{CJK*}}},
  sortname={{Chen Tong}},
  year={2012},
  title={Obtaining fatty acids from insect larvae},
  howpublished={Investigacion y Comercializacion
  Biotecnologica Omebit S.A, Santiago. US8895767 B2},
  note={Jun. 11, 2010},
}
@article{a,
  author={A. Uthor},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  year=2013,
}
@article{b,
  author={T. Best},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  year=2013,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{chin2012pat}, \cite{a}, \cite{b}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Note

The `filecontents*` environment is just for convenience in preparing self-contained examples. You don't need it, just supply your own `.bib` file in the `\addbibresource` instruction.

Comment: Thank you! Interesting enough, neither works, but at least I know now that it should work! Using the first method, I get a "package inputenc error: unicode char \U8:(code) not set up for use with latex", and the second method, really interesting, gets me a "Incomplete \iffalse, all textwas ignored after line (printbibliography macro)". No idea where that stems from

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, looks like everything works OK now (2019) using plain bib entry `author={彤陈},` in xelatex with `fontspec` and a suitable font, and biblatex/biber:

[image: chinese characters]

MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{chin2012pat,
%  author={{\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}彤陈\end{CJK*}}},
  author={彤陈}, 
  sortname={{Chen Tong}},
  year={2012},
  title={Obtaining fatty acids from insect larvae},
  howpublished={Investigacion y Comercializacion
  Biotecnologica Omebit S.A, Santiago. US8895767 B2},
  note={Jun. 11, 2010},
}
@article{a,
  author={A. Uthor},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  year=2013,
}
@article{b,
  author={T. Best},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  year=2013,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Noto Serif CJK SC}

%\usepackage{graphicx}

%\usepackage[bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{chin2012pat}, \cite{a}, \cite{b}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```